# Convert any element that does not start with a specific string to NA

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a large data frame that looks like df2.
I want to convert any element across columns code1, code2 that does not start with
AT to NA.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- tibble(type=c("Jeep", "4x4", "convertible"), 
              code1=c("ATG1",NA, "ATG2"), 
              code2=c("random", "ATG3", "xyz"))
df2
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   type        code1 code2 
#>   <chr>       <chr> <chr> 
#> 1 Jeep        ATG1  random
#> 2 4x4         <NA>  ATG3  
#> 3 convertible ATG2  xyz
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I want my data to look like this
#>   type        code1 code2
#>           
#> 1 Jeep        ATG1  NA
#> 2 4x4           ATG3
#> 3 convertible ATG2  NA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `replace` and `grepl`:

```r
df2 %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("code"), ~ replace(.x, !grepl("^AT", .x), NA)))
```

Comment: I love this one! how did I miss using grepl

Answer (score 3):

You could do

```r
df2 %>%
  mutate(across(code1:code2, ~ifelse(substr(.x, 1, 2) == 'AT', .x, NA)))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   type        code1 code2
#>   <chr>       <chr> <chr>
#> 1 Jeep        ATG1  NA   
#> 2 4x4         NA    ATG3 
#> 3 convertible ATG2  NA
```

Comment: this is very cool!

Answer (score 1):

Using `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df2 %>%
   mutate(across(starts_with('code'), ~ case_when(str_detect(.x, '^AT')~ .x)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  type        code1 code2
  <chr>       <chr> <chr>
1 Jeep        ATG1  <NA> 
2 4x4         <NA>  ATG3 
3 convertible ATG2  <NA>
```

Comment: case_when that's even more beautiful